# Rotating an IMU around X axis, but all 3 angles changes

Tags: rotation, quaternions

I am having trouble with Euler angles of an IMU. I have an IMU that gives quaternion and Euler angles. Such questions like bias and so on will be done by the manufacturer and it like a black box for me. I have to trust on it. 
My question is as follows: If I rotate IMU around his X-axis, so just the X angle should change its value (for example Roll angle) and it doesn't matter how I oriented the IMU in the space before. But if I rotate it around X Axes I get changes also on other 2 angles. It is like the rotation is not in IMU own coordinate system.